# ExtJS 7.3 modern no Vtype available

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs7

I'd like to limit the input from users when they enter a time duration:

```
08:00
```

or when certain settings are enabled

```
-08:00
```

This would be possible with an input mask but the '-' is optional so that is out of the question. I am used to using vtype but this is not available in the modern version and I do not see an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'vtype' is not available but you can use validators

```
validators: /^[0-9]{1,5}[:. ;]{0,1}[0-5][0-9]$/
```

and for the negative duration

```
validators: /^-{0,1}[0-9]{1,5}[:. ;]{0,1}[0-5][0-9]$/
```